Opamp input signals not ideal but output is correct
got this old circuit. Rectangular pulses (red) look not ideal but somehow output pulse is a clean waveform. Is this because of the 2.5VDC voltage always present at inverting input of U1?

I disconnected 2.5VDC but U1 output is still a clean rectangular pulse. Why?


V(in) is completely floating wrt ground (and you are measuring it relative to ground).
If you put a high-value resistor from the low side of V2 you will get different waveforms. You can also add the aforementioned resistor and plot the difference between the two inputs V(in) - V(inm), for example, if you name the low side of V2 'inm'.
You'll also need resistors to some voltage wrt ground on each of the inputs of the op-amps to deal with bias currents, as @Autistic says. Those voltages should be within the common-mode input range of the op-amp (operated as a comparator) when operated from 0V/-5V.
It's not clear what's intended here- the output of U2 goes nowhere through the R-C parallel combination and neither op-amp input has a DC path even if we ignore C1 and C2 due to series capacitor C4.

Your red input wave is wandering on the finite     but very small bias current on the opamp input pin .This would not work in real life .Deal with this and the waveforms will be as expected. This    classic mistake is really common when people do intergraters  with opamps .

What you have built there is a differential amplifier, and you're seeing the very thing that they exist for - to remove any "common mode" component of the input.
You have two input potentials, (the left ends of R1 and R2), and these potentials, individually, are somewhat ambiguous, as seen in the red trace. They both seem to "wander" (because of capacitors C1 and C2), but they do have a very well defined difference.
That is, the difference between those two input potentials is the difference between the two ends of source V2. Even if the potential of one or both ends of V2 is, on its own, not clear or obvious, their potential difference is a 12V square wave. This is also visible in the red trace, as the peak-to-peak distance of that signal, always 12V.
The differential amplifier produces a voltage output which is proportional to the difference between its two inputs, and any "common mode" offset (the absolute potential offset of the pair) is ignored, rejected. This is why you see a very clean square output, with the slow drift over time of the two inputs being absent.
As a side note, this is why differential amplifiers are so useful in signal transmission. If a signal is transmitted as a pair of potentials carried on two wires, and those wires are close to each other, then any noise picked up will be equal in both paths. Then, by subtracting one wire's potential from the other, what's left is the original signal, with the noise cancelled out.
Here you can consider the drifting "offset" as noise common to both paths, hence the name "common mode", which is being cancelled by the differential amplifier's "subtraction" operation.
